# Qfield Cloud API Error

Tags: api, qfieldsync

I have a project i created new from scratch. I have opened qfield sync logged in and clicked on the little blue cloud with the star saying 'create new project' I have chosen the Convert currently open project option and stored it in a local directory I press 'create' and the conversion process seems to go to 100% but then the whole process stops and i get a red 'QFieldcloud rejected project creation [api_error] API Error'. Any clues what this means and how i'd solve?